# Docker compose scaling down and Consul

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose file with several services:

```
services:
  consul:
    image: consul:latest
    ports:
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8301:8301"
      - "8302:8302"
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:53/udp"      
    command: "agent -server -ui -bootstrap-expect=1 -client=0.0.0.0"
 microservice1:
   image: xxx:latest
   ports:
     - "8080"
 microservice2:
   image: yyy:latest
   ports:
     - "8080"
```

Services are successfully registered on Consul, health check is passing.
I scale up one microservice:
docker-compose up microservice1=3

all new containers are properly shown in consul.

But, when I scale down microservice I have orange status in Consul and logs are showing something like this:

> 2016/07/28 18:58:38 [WARN] agent: http request failed
>   'http://27dd6662f944:8080/health': Get
>   http://27dd6662f944:8080/health: dial tcp: lookup 27dd6662f944 on
>   127.0.0.11:53: no such host

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
services:
  consul:
    **hostname: consul**
    image: consul:latest
    ports:
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8301:8301"
      - "8302:8302"
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:53/udp"      
    command: "agent -server -ui -bootstrap-expect=1 -client=0.0.0.0"
 microservice1:
   image: xxx:latest
   ports:
     - "8080"
 microservice2:
   image: yyy:latest
   ports:
     - "8080"
```

Add hostname for consul image...